# How to force react app to be opened in full browser instead of embedded one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

So I noticed that **Google OAuth** login functionality doesn't work in my React app when opened in embedded browser.

In my case it's **IOS Facebook messenger**  browser but it seems like it is the same regardless of embedded browser type / operating system.

Google disallowed OAuth in embedded browsers.

[image]

Is it achievable to have a button which will open the app in native device browser?